# Autocomplete - Fails randomly after a few uses (how do i debug?)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, simplemodal, jqote

All-

So I'm using qjote2 to render some templates, and using simple modal to display a window.  This window has a simple text box which leverages autocomplete.

For some strange reason, autocomplete will stop working after I open and close the modal about 8 or so times.  It's quite strange.  I DO have 2 of the exact same named (class) text boxes but I bend them both regardless which modal is displayed.

No errors are thrown, does anyone know how I can debug this further? I know for a fact that it is bound as the below prints to log (I call the below whenever the modal is shown):

```
$(document).find('.object_search').each(function() {    

    console.log("FOUND! " + $(this));
    $(this).val('');

    // bind our object search
    $(this).autocomplete({
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can debug this further? I'm pretty new to using jquery this much, so am just used to seeing errors vs. knowing how to debug when something doesn't operate properly.

Edit: I attempted to put this on fiddle, but it jqote won't render. You can view the EXACT same thing here: http://quests.ceilingfansoftware.com/test.php

Comment: show more of your modal code... the snippet shown appears fine

Comment: For instance, try reproducing it in a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). By reducing the complexity, you may find what you did wrong

Comment: I'm actually trying to do that now but none of the ajax calls succeed because it's on a different domain.  Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/eeX3g/

Comment: I'm going to guess jqote doesn't play well with fiddle

Comment: I got it to work here, now trying to get it on fiddle: http://quests.ceilingfansoftware.com/test.php (just click the edit button, and do save/close repeatedly and it will eventually break)